# Apache JMeter - How can we test different elements' response time?

Tags: jmeter

How can we test different elements' response time? I am really quite new to Jmeter. But nowhere could I find how to test response time of some particular elements only e.g. assume that in a  page there are many images present. Are they loaded properly ? If yes, how much time they took?

I will be really grateful if you could help me with that by providing some link or tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jmeter is server side testing tool.(jmeter will give you total response time for response containing images and other payload at a specific load on server)

What you are asking comes under client side page rendering.

For loading of images you can use client side tools and browser plugins or profilers. 
I would prefer browser plugins for this like firebug, pagespeed or performance testing sites like GTMetrix etc. 
they will give total page rendering time (for all requests,images,reponse,css,js everything)

Hope this solves your question

Comment: Can we do something with HTTP request method(GET,POST etc),content-encoding to just retrieve images?

Comment: I think no, what response to send to a specific request is determined by server which is predefined i.e. design logic. its not like db query. what you are asking can be done through browser plugins

Comment: hit the server which you are accessing and you will get response time and rendering time of images,text,css,js etc. completely but for a single user. I think this is what you want.